# optimization for faster calculation on python defaultdict

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have such a script;

```
for b in range(len(xy_alignments.keys())):
                print str(b) + " : " + str(len(xy_alignments.keys()))
                x = xy_alignments.keys()[b][0]
                y = xy_alignments.keys()[b][1]
                yx_prob = yx_alignments[(y,x)] / x_phrases[x]
                xy_prob = xy_alignments[(x,y)] / y_phrases[y]
                line_str = x + "\t" + y + "\t" + str(yx_prob) + "\t" + str(xy_prob) + "\n"
                of.write(line_str.encode("utf-8"))
        of.close()
```

`xy_alignments`, `yx_alignments`, `x_phrases`, and `y_phrases` are 
**python defaultdict** variables which involve millions of keys.

When I run the loop above, it runs damn slowly.

Do python lovers have a suggestion to make it fast?

Thanks,

Comment: Remove the `print`. It is probably the slowest part of that code by far.

Comment: But it is very very slow. It takes 2 seconds to skip one loop.

Comment: Now it takes 1 second per loop. But still so bad.

Comment: Every time you call xy_alignments.keys() you create a new list. Move the list of keys to outside the loop, you only need to create this once

Comment: Same with `len(xy_alignments.keys())`; move that out of the loop. FWIW, you can also call `len` directly on `xy_alignments`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a more idiomatic version, that should also be faster.

```
for (x, y), xy_alignment in xy_alignments.iteritems():
    yx_prob = yx_alignments[(y, x)] / x_phrases[x]
    xy_prob = xy_alignment / y_phrases[y]
    of.write(b'%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n' % (x, y, yx_prob, xy_prob))
```

This

- saves the `key()` calls which create new lists every time,
- saves one dict lookup by using `iteritems()`,
- saves string allocations by using string formatting, and
- saves the `encode()` call because all output is in the ascii range anyway.